# Syntax Error: expecting rightparen before colon

Tags: syntax, actionscript

I'm working with ActionScript3.0 on a basic movement engine.  When I try to test my code, I get this error:

```
MovementClass.as, Line 44, Column 22    1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before colon.
```

I get this for lines 44, 52, 60, and 68 of the following code; these are the lines reading **heroGoing<*direction*>(e:TimerEvent);**

```
package  {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;


public class MovementClass extends MovieClip {
    var reference:Reference = new Reference();
    var hero:Hero = new Hero();
    var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy();
    var wall:Wall = new Wall();

    //Timer
    var moveTimer:Timer = new Timer(25, 10)

    //Booleans
    var movingHeroRight:Boolean = false;
    var movingHeroLeft:Boolean = false;
    var movingHeroUp:Boolean = false;
    var movingHeroDown:Boolean = false;

    public function MovementClass() {
        hero.x = stage.stageWidth * .5;
        hero.y = stage.stageHeight * .5;
        addChild(hero);
        startEngine();
    }

    public function startEngine():void {
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, movementHandler);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, stopHandler);
    }

    public function movementHandler(keyDown:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if (keyDown.keyCode == 39) {
            if (movingHeroLeft == true, movingHeroUp == true, movingHeroDown == true) {
                return;
            } else {
                heroGoingRight(e:TimerEvent);
                movingHeroRight = true;
                moveTimer.start;
            }
        } else if (keyDown.keyCode == 37) {
            if (movingHeroRight == true, movingHeroUp == true, movingHeroDown == true) {
                return;
            } else {
                heroGoingLeft(e:TimerEvent);
                movingHeroLeft = true;
                moveTimer.start;
            }
        } else if (keyDown.keyCode == 38) {
            if (movingHeroLeft == true, movingHeroRight == true, movingHeroDown == true) {
                return;
            } else {
                heroGoingUp(e:TimerEvent);
                movingHeroUp = true;
                moveTimer.start;
            }
        } else if (keyDown.keyCode == 40) {
            if (movingHeroLeft == true, movingHeroUp == true, movingHeroRight == true) {
                return;
            } else {
                heroGoingDown(e:TimerEvent);
                movingHeroDown = true;
                moveTimer.start;
            }
        }
        //moveTimer.start();
    }

    function heroGoingUp(eUp:TimerEvent):void {
        if (movingHeroUp == true) {
            reference.y += 5;
        }
    }

    function heroGoingDown(eDown:TimerEvent):void {
        if (movingHeroDown == true) {
            reference.y -= 5;
        }
    }

    function heroGoingLeft(eLeft:TimerEvent):void {
        if (movingHeroLeft == true) {
            reference.x += 5;
        }
    }

    function heroGoingRight(eRight:TimerEvent):void {
        if (movingHeroRight == true) {
            reference.x -= 5;
        }
    }

    public function stopHandler(keyUp:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if (movingHeroRight == true) {
            movingHeroRight = false;
        } else if (movingHeroLeft == true) {
            movingHeroLeft = false;
        } else if (movingHeroUp == true) {
            movingHeroUp = false;
        } else if (movingHeroDown == true) {
            movingHeroDown = false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would be nice if you added lines numbers to code.

Comment: Even better, tag your posting with the language you're using.  Be specific if the release version matters (e.g. python2 rather than just python).

Comment: Improved code & message formatting.  Made minor wording updates.  Added C++ tag

Comment: @Prune Why?! It clearly isn’t C++ …

Comment: Thanks.  Massive ... well, the explanation is too long and detailed.  Distraction at the end of the edit.  Tag removed.

Comment: It's actionscript 3.0 though....

Comment: user Prune's answer confuses me a bit.  How do I declare e:TimerEvent appropriately before I use it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the first **heroMoving** call:

```
            heroGoingRight(e:TimerEvent);
```

The compiler thinks you're trying to declare a variable *in situ*.  Declare **e:TimerEvent** appropriately, *before* you use it, and you should be fine.